# Chrome Lighthouse 403 forbidden on production server

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, pagespeed, lighthouse, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to run Chrome lighthouse on my production server. It stops returning error saying `Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Status code: 403)`.

It is working fine in my local and staging setup servers. Servers hosted on AWS and cloudflare as firewall

Answer (score 0):

As stated on this [page](https://support.speedcurve.com/docs/troubleshooting-lighthouse)

> A common cause of failures is Lighthouse being blocked by bot detection or DDOS protection software, resulting in a 403 error. This can be resolved by allowing web traffic with the "Chrome-Lighthouse" user-agent string.

Answer (score -2):

This is kind of frequent problem developers faces during production on a server with higher loading time, to summarize:
It occurs because of the following issues:

- Unresponsive server
- Unstable/Slow internet connection.

*Please try to rerun the test then it will work.*

Comment: Follow this to improve further
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/#devtools